# What is C# equivalent of PHP's mysql_fetch_array function?

Tags: c#, sql, equivalent

I am learning C#/ASP.NET and I am wondering what the C# equivalent of the following PHP code is?
I know the userid, and I want to fetch the rows from this table into the array of the variable "row", so I then can use it as "row['name']" and "row['email'].

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email, name FROM mytable WHERE id=7");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("Email: %s  Name: %s", $row["email"], $row["name"]);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need row. .Net would normally be a an IDataReader or a Datatable or even more modern a collection. Don't try and create PHP.Net you'll come unstuck and quick.

Comment: I don't need row at all, what I meant in my post was to show how I would do it in PHP, and the question was what is the equivalent? I don't mean to make it as similar as possible, but how would I go about getting the same end result (a variable with the results) in C#?

Comment: Perhaps my initial question was a bit unclear or not very well asked, but I hope you can understand my underlying intentions :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the same as `mysql_fetch_array` but i assume that.
You can use [`IDBCommmand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executereader.aspx) to create an [`IDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) and use that to fill an `Object[]` with all fields of the row.

For example (using SQL-Server):

```
// use using statements to ensure that connections are disposed/closed (all implementing IDisposable)
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email, name FROM mytable WHERE id=@id", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);  // use parameters to avoid sql-injection
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        { 
            var fields = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            // following fills an object[] with all fields of the current line, 
            // is this similar to mysql_fetch_array?
            int count  = reader.GetValues(fields);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

> I don't mean to make it as similar as possible, but how would I go about getting the same end result (a variable with the results) in C#

That's a matter of taste. You could use some kind of ORM like Enity-Framework, NHibernate, LINQ-To-SQL or Stackoverflow's Micro-ORM [Dapper.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET)(what i'm using currently) or plain ADO.NET (as shown above).

You can use a custom class that you fill manually with a `DataReader` or a `DataTable` which schema is loaded automatically.

For example (here using MySQL):

```
DataTable tblEmail = new DataTable();
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MySQL))
using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Email, Name FROM Email WHERE id=@id", con))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
    da.Fill(tblEmail);
}

if (tblEmail.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    DataRow row  = tblEmail.Rows[0];
    String email = row.Field<String>("Email");
    String name  = row.Field<String>("Name");
}
```

As you can see, there are many ways in .NET. I have shown just two with ADO.NET.

Answer (score 2):

There's no true equivalent. Having been a PHP developer in the past, I'd say the closest thing is to use a data adapter and fill a data table. Here's a reference to [DbDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx).

I'm not sure about the MySql driver but if you're using Sql Server here's some code to get you started:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var table = new DataTable("tbl_objects");
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_name", connection);
    adapter.Fill(table);
}
```

Then, you can iterate over the rows in the table:

```
foreach(var row in table)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", row["ColumnName"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your result with a foreach loop as follows:

```
  foreach(var row in result)
  { 
      console.writeline("Email:" + row.Email, "Name:", row.Name);
  }
```

Is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

EDIT

In fact i have just seen you only have one result.

Then you can skip the foreach loop altogether

Answer (score 0):

You need a connection to a database.

Assuming you are using mysql and an odbc connection.

```
var connectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" +
                     "SERVER=localhost;" +
                     "DATABASE=test;" +
                     "UID=venu;" +
                     "PASSWORD=venu;" +
                     "OPTION=3");


using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT email, name FROM mytable WHERE id=7", connection);

    connection.Open();

    // Execute the DataReader and access the data.
    OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //do stuff with the data here row by row the reader is a cursor
    }

    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();
```

alternately you could use an odbcdataadapter and a datatable if you wanted all the results in a table you could use like an array.

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent in .net would be something like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataRow("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;", "select * from foo");
            Console.WriteLine(foo["Column"]);
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you are using the MySql Data Connector http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Do note there are better ways available in .net to connect to databases, but I think for a line by line, this is about as close to the PHP as you can get.